# Global variable in Appdelegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am saving some data to a variable of appdelegate from a viewcontroller & fetching it from another view controller.Below is the code of app delegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController: UINavigationController?
var mainDic:NSMutableDictionary?
```

Code to set the mainDic

```
func filterResponse(response:NSDictionary){

    var appDelegate=AppDelegate()
    appDelegate.mainDic=response.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableDictionary
}
```

Code to fetch the dictionary.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
println(appDelegate.mainDic)
```

The issue is I am getting the output nil.Please make me correct.

Comment: It's not the purpose of the appDelegate. Read some tutorials like [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is your error

```
var appDelegate=AppDelegate() //You create a new instance, not get the exist one
```

You need to access the exiting AppDelegate

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 4.0**

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 
 let aVariable = appDelegate.value
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let aVariable = appDelegate.someVariable
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let aVariable = appDelegate.someVariable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func appDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
  return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```